# Manual contribution, add contact that is not found

Tags: contributions

While adding a contribution manually, the first step is to find a contact. If the contact is not found, I remember being able to select 'new contact' from the bottom of the autocomplete list. As at 4.7.25 is it possible to add a contact from the contribution page or do we need to move to 'new individual' if the contact is not found while taking payments?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

It does show up the link to create contact when no match is found.

[image]

From your shared image it looks like the user has limited permission to create contact/access CiviCRM profile or also check if 'New Individual' Profile is enabled under Reserved profiles.

Comment: Something weird anyway. I created a copy of the site upgraded it to 4.7.35 and this worked. Copied both drupal and civicrm. Then deployed it to the production site, ran the upgrade/clear templates cache etc. Still doesn't work.

Comment: Second copy of the site on 5.1.2 - also fine.

Answer (score 0):

"is it possible to add a contact from the contribution page"

Yes, when you visit the Contribution page select the 'want to do this as a different person' eg from http://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/contribute/transact?reset=1&id=1 or just bookmark the link
http://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/contribute/transact?cid=0&reset=1&id=1

the important bit is the cid=0

Then you can fill out the Contribution Page as anonymous and use that approach to create the Contact.

If this isn't a useful Answer then I really haven't understood your question.

Comment: I think Pradeep has answered the right question ;-)

Comment: although in my defence i think it is often a better approach than doing via backend since it is likely to have all the fields you need in one place